# Eclipse won't save html file with dynamic charset

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf template engine, and want to get the charset attribute value for the meta tag on the head block from my project properties, i.e :
`<meta th:charset="${@environment.getProperty('html.charset')}">`

But when I want to save my html file I get this pop-up error :

> Save could not be completed. Try File > Save As... if the problem persists.
> Reason: 
> Character encoding "${@environment.getProperty('html.charset')}" is not a legal character encoding.

I even tried to save the file from outside of eclipse, but when back on eclipse and want to open the file, I couldn't access it and got this error :

> Unsupported Character Encoding
> Character encoding "${@environment.getProperty('html.charset')}" is not supported by this platform.
> Set Encoding...

I tried to suspend all validators on eclipse Preferences but this doesn't resolve the problem.

Any ideas for help ? Thanks in advance.

I'm on Mac OS and using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers, Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charset value is being used, regardless of the prefix, to read and write the file correctly. That there is a prefix on the attribute in a non-prefixed `meta` tag is a clue that it should be ignored by the normal encoding detection. Please open a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Source%20Editing&component=wst.html) for this.

For a workaround, force the use of the encoding you want using the file's **Properties** dialog's **Resource** page (get there by right-clicking on the file).

[image: Resources page in the Properties dialog]

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem for this file. I will report the bug to fix that permanently.